# What suitable regex to exclude a word

Tags: java, regex

I have the following sentences:

delete all from my list

Delete from my list

remove list

remove all from my list

Akash delete all from my list

Here is my regex:

```
(?i)^.*(!delete all|!remove all|remove|delete)(.*?)(from my list|from the list|from list|list|reminders|shopping list|reminders list)(.*)$
```

I dont want this to match 'delete all' or 'remove all' but the above does not match even I have mentioned `!delete all|!remove all` confused!

Comment: Regex negation doesn't involve the exclamation point.

Comment: So how do I reframe it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) here:

```
(?i)(?:delete|remove)(?!\s+all)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/A3hhd9/1)

`(?!\s+all)` is a negative lookahead assertion that fails the match if we have whitespace and `all` after `delete` or `remove`.